# Multiprocessing performance reduction

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to speed up a nested loop execution by parallelising an inner loop with `multiprocessing` module. In the simple example N jobs are repeatedly running multiple times and the problem is that elapsed time of each iteration is dramatically increasing. I think the reason is a growth of a global `global_res` list which being copied in every thread, but I don't know how to prevent it. Is there any way how to directly tell `mp.Process` which global variables are needed?

```
import time
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp

def process_with_big_output(ret_list, i):
    aux = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=100000)
    ret_list[i] = aux

repeats=100
elapsed=[]
only_parallel=[]

global_res = [None for _ in range(repeats)]
for itr in range(repeats):
    start = time.time()
    N = 1000
    all_res = [0 for _ in range(N)]
    manager = mp.Manager()
    return_list = manager.list(range(N))

    jobs = []
    for i in range(N):
        p = mp.Process(target=process_with_big_output,
                       args=(return_list, i))
        jobs.append(p)

    for j in jobs:
        j.start()
    for j in jobs:
        j.join()

    for i in range(N):
        all_res[i] = return_list[i]
        
    only_parallel.append(time.time()-start)
        
    global_res[itr] = all_res
    
    elapsed.append(time.time()-start)
    if itr%10:
        print(only_parallel[-1], elapsed[-1])
```

Comment: Too many processes. Use a Pool!

Comment: Use a [`mp.Manager.Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.SyncManager.Queue) instead of a `mp.Manager.List`. This will avoid the overhead of copying everything in it to every *process*.

Comment: I don't think it's a question of `global_res` being copied; it's just a question of it growing increasingly larger and larger taking up more virtual memory and degrading performance. Aside from that you should use `multiprocessing.Pool` with the `map` method, which will return the complete `all_res` list you seek with one call. Managed lists and queues are slow and there is no point in starting more processes than cores you have when the tasks being done are 100% CPU.